# ReferenceError: mydialog is not defined

Tags: javascript

Una vez más vengo a solicitar ayuda con un sitio que estoy haciendo para practicar. Tengo un archivo **js** que hace la función de subida de imágenes para mi sitio que me funciona bien en uno pero en otro no *(en el entorno de producción funciona pero no en development)*.

Mi código es este pero como ven me da error:

> "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: mydialog is not defined"

El **jquery** estoy seguro que está cargando bien porque sino las otras funciones de la web dieran error. Me gustaría saber también cómo depurar este tipo de errores y al presentarse saber buscar por lo básico. Obviamente antes de hacer la pregunta busqué información por mi cuenta pero no encontré nada. Gracias

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.avatar-big-cont').click(function(){
  $('.menu-subir').show();
  $('#ImgPo').hide();
 });
 
 $('.menu-subir > *').click(function(){
  var clase = $(this).attr('class');
  switch(clase){
   case 'imagen-pc':
    mydialog.close_button = false;
    mydialog.mask_close = true;
    mydialog.show();
    mydialog.title('Insertar imagen');
    mydialog.body('<div id="LPortada"><input name="file-avatar" id="file-avatar" size="30" type="file"><br/><button onclick="portada.upload(this)" class="boto verde local">Subir Imagen</button></div>');
    mydialog.buttons(false);
    mydialog.center();
                console.log(clase); 
   break;
   case 'imagen-url':
    mydialog.close_button = false;
    mydialog.mask_close = true;
    mydialog.show();
    mydialog.title('Insertar imagen');
    mydialog.body('<div id="RPortada"><input type="text" name="url-avatar" id="url-avatar" size="45"><br/><button onclick="portada.upload(this);" class="boto verde url">Subir Imagen</button></div>');
    mydialog.buttons(false);
    mydialog.center();
    $('input[name=url-avatar]').focus();
   break;
  }
 });   
});
```

```css
#BoxPortada .avatar-big-cont {
    width: 230px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 170px;
    border: solid 4px #fff;
    outline: dashed 1px #CCC;
    background: url(../i/cam.png) no-repeat center 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.menu-subir {
    background: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.imagen-pc, .imagen-url {
    background: #2594EC;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
}
#BoxPortada {
    float: left;
    width: 258px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
#BoxPortada .avatar-loading {
    width: 230px;
    height: 170px;
    background: #fff url(../i/spinner.gif) center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form_opciones">
    <label>Imagen de Portada</label>
    <div id="BoxPortada">
 <input type="hidden" name="portada" value="{$tsDraft.b_portada}"/> 
 <div class="sidebar-tabs clearbeta">
  <div class="avatar-big-cont">
   <div style="display: none" class="avatar-loading"></div>
   <div id="ImgPo">
    <img src="{if $tsDraft.b_portada}{$tsConfig.url}/files/portadas/toup{$tsDraft.b_portada}P240X180.jpg{/if}" class="portada-big" id="portada-img"/>
    <p>Haz clic aqui para subir una imagen</p>
   </div> 
   <div class="menu-subir">
    <div class="imagen-pc">Desde mi computadora</div>
    <div class="imagen-url">Desde internet (URL)</div>
    {*<div class="imagen-url">Desde el post</div>*}
   </div>
   
  </div>  
 </div>   
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: En donde defines la variable `mydialog`?

Comment: Estoy revisando mi otro script y no veo que se defina en ningún lado. Cómo defino la variable?

Comment: @AlvinCortez lo que indica es que no tienes definida la variable myDialog, te recomendaría que leas la documentación de la Libreria que utilizas para crear el dialogo si es que utilizas alguna.

Comment: Probablemente solo necesitas incluir <script src="ruta/nombre_script.js"></script> para hacerlo funcionar.